# "Would you like to have responses to your questions sent to you via email" link is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just asked a question on SO. This is the URL that got created: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738518/appstats-are-only-working-for-one-wsgiapplication`.

I tried clicking the ""Would you like to have responses to your questions sent to you via email?" link shown at the end of the page, but it didn't do anything. The FireFox error console noted this:

> Error: $ is not defined
>   Source File: [Appstats are only working for one WSGIApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738518/appstats-are-only-working-for-one-wsgiapplication)
>   Line: 271

> Error: no element found
>   Source File: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9738518/ivc/2b4f?_=1331906555908
>   Line: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, this will be fixed in the next build.